# How to import money data using IMPORTXML?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying using `ImportXML` with XPath code to get currency rate, but this code not working.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"; "/gesmes:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube[@currency='USD']@rate")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(
 IMPORTDATA("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"); 
 "where Col1 contains 'USD'"; 0); "rate='(.*)'")
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11HOrh0DpvWhqngHR3WcdC_feIk3NzkMlwO7lbz9jzDw/edit?usp=sharing